# Google Sign in DomainException: OpenSSL unable to verify data

Tags: php, firebase, jwt, google-signin

I am trying to integrate Google Sign-in to a website(PHP) login page.

The development environment of the website is localhost but I have mapped the site to a domain via **/etc/hosts** file. So, currently, I am accessing the site via a domain like **dev.test.com/mysite**

I have generated a **client ID** for the google sign in API by providing **dev.test.com** as the Authorized JavaScript origin.

I could successfully implement to receive the Token ID from the google to my site.

Then to validate the token I use **Google Client API library** as google recommended.

```
function googleLogin(){
    $idToken = $_POST['idtoken'];

    error_log($idToken);

    $client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => getConfiguration('google_sign_in_api_key')]);  

    $payload = $client->verifyIdToken($idToken);

    error_log('######### '. $payload);

    if ($payload) {
      $userid = $payload['sub'];
      // If request specified a G Suite domain:
      //$domain = $payload['hd'];

      error_log('######### '. $payload);


    } else {
      // Invalid ID token
    }
}
```

Referring to the above function **$payload** should not empty if the validation success.

I have put some logs inside Google Client API library internal classes and found the following exception.

> DomainException: OpenSSL unable to verify data: error:0906D06C:PEM
>   routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line in
>   /var/www/html/google-sign-in/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php:229\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/html/google-sign-in/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php(108):
>   Firebase\JWT\JWT::verify('eyJhbGciOiJSUzI...',
>   '*\xF6\x04\xD8uq\xA2\x91R\xA5T\x01A\x96t...', '-----BEGIN
>   PUBL...', 'RS256')\n#1
>   /var/www/html/google-sign-in/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/AccessToken/Verify.php(105):
>   Firebase\JWT\JWT::decode('eyJhbGciOiJSUzI...', '-----BEGIN PUBL...',
>   Array)\n#2
>   /var/www/html/google-sign-in/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php(721):
>   Google_AccessToken_Verify->verifyIdToken('eyJhbGciOiJSUzI...',
>   '1022197204491-p...')\n#3
>   /var/www/html/google-sign-in/social-login-controller.php(21):
>   Google_Client->verifyIdToken('eyJhbGciOiJSUzI...')\n#4

What may be the reason related to this issue?